# R - %||% pipe operator

Tags: r, r-usethis, r-library

I'm trying to reuse snippets of code from the [`r-lib`](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis) repository. I can't find where this particular pipe operator is defined:

```
getOption("usethis.description") %||% list()
```

Could anyone direct me to the source code for this pipe operator?

Comment: Fun fact, this has been included in `ggplot2` as `ggplot2:::"%||%"` since at least 2009, with the comment "Analog of || from ruby".

Comment: `plot.stepfun` uses it in line 16, obviously since 1997. I wonder, why it evaluates, although `rlang` isn't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Answer credit to @akrun.

`%||%` is defined in `rlang`:

```
`%||%` <- function (x, y) 
{
    if (is_null(x)) 
        y
    else x
}
```